# Simple Objective C Question: How can I get access to a variable from other class?

Tags: objective-c

It is my MyName.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface MyName : NSObject {
    NSString *myName;

}

@property(readwrite) NSString *myName;


@end
```

and this is the .m:

```
#import "MyName.h"


@implementation MyName

@synthesize myName;

@end
```

It is my another controller.m

```
#import "MyName.h"
#import "MainViewController.h"

@implementation MainViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.myName = @"My Name is Peter";
}

......


@end
```

And I get the Request for member "myName" in something may a structure or union error. wt's happen?

Answer (score 0):

If you're declaring "myName" as a member of the MyName class, you need to instantiate a MyName object and set your variable there.  Right now you're trying to set it on MainViewController.

Comment: can u give me some example, I still don't understand.

Comment: It sounds like you may not be familiar with object oriented programming.  You need to understand how classes/objects work to get much done in Obj-C.  I can point you at some resources if you'd like.

Comment: I get ur point, well, do I need to make a init method for  "MyName"? But actually, I just want something can be a middle man for me to pass two view between different controller.